# How to loop through x number of items in css?

Tags: css, loops, animation, sass

I have a list of unknown number of items and I would like to loop through all items and animate them with CSS. All the CSS loops i have found are all based on a known number of items, is there a loop that I can use if don't know how many items to loop over?

Currently my code looks like this:

```css
        @for $i from 1 through 10 {
            li:nth-child(#{$i}) {
                transition: all .3s ease-in;
                transition-delay: #{$i * .15s};
            }
        }
```

I need the `10` in this snippet to be `x`.

Any input is much appreciated.

Comment: Short answer: No

Comment: @Jax-p would you have any ideas of a work around?

Comment: Javacript is your best option

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to make like a slider or a carousel? Because than you can try out OwlCarousel, it's a library/plugin, where you can loop very easy.

https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/